# SourceTreeでHEADが指していたコミットが消えてしまった

Tags: git, sourcetree

Git初心者です。
当初、以下の画像の上部のような状態でした（上部は私が記憶を頼りに画像編集してつくったものです）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私が「Master」をダブルクリックしたらチェックアウトしてMasterのブランチになったのは良いのですが、画像下部のようにHEADが指していたブランチとそのコミットが消えてしまいました。

なんとかして画像上部の状態に戻したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: git reflog が質問者様のおしいものかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 git reflogとgit checkout *** でもとに戻すことが出来ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git reflog が質問者様のほしいものかもしれません。 – Yuki Inoue